# Set dynamic checkbox list values to checked, based upon SQL CE query

Tags: razor, checkbox, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I am using WebMatrix 3.0 and SQL CE to create a .cshtml webform.

Problem: I have a list of checkboxes that are dynamically created by querying all records in a table.  For each checkbox with value ID I want to set checked="checked" only if the value ID corresponds to a row in another table.

More detail:
I have a database that contains two tables of basic data ("person" and "socialMedia") and a third table ("persMedia"). The "persMedia" table exists to manage the many-to-many relationship between "person" and "socialMedia". Table "person" has a primary key named ID. Table "socialMedia" also has a primary key named ID. Table "persMedia" has two columns named personID and siteID. Suppose a person is listed in the "person" table where ID=1. Suppose that person has two social media accounts listed in the "socialMedia" table with ID values of 4 and 7.  In that case, there will be two rows in the "persMedia" table with personID and siteID values of 1,4 and 1,7.

I am creating a form where an id value is requested from the URL. I then query the "person" table for the row with the primary key equal to the id value.  Then, I create a list of checkboxes.  There is one checkbox for each record in the "socialMedia" table.  So, each checkbox has name="socialM" and value="@social.ID".  So far, so good.

Here is the problem. For each checkbox, I want to set the checked attribute to "checked" if there is a row in the "persMedia" table with a personID record equal to id and a siteID value equal to @social.ID.  How do I do this?  I tried several variations of the code below.

```
var id=Request["id"];
var SQLSELECT = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE @0=ID";
var db = Database.Open("mydatabase");
var person = db.QuerySingle(SQLSELECT,id);

var getSocMedia = db.Query("SELECT ID, site FROM socialMedia");

var getPersMedia = db.Query("SELECT personID FROM persMedia");
```

These lines below create a checkbox list with no boxes checked, by default.

```
<p>Accounts:</p>
    @foreach(var socialM in getSocMedia){
        <input type="checkbox" name="social" value="@socialM.ID" />@socialM.site<br />
    }
```

When I modified the lines above, in an attempt to check some of the boxes based upon the query of the table with the many-to-many relationship, here is what I came up with.

```
<p>Accounts:</p>
    @foreach(var socialM in getSocMedia){
        <input type="checkbox" name="social" value="@socialM.ID" checked=@foreach(var persmed in getPersMedia){if(persmed.personID != null){"checked";}}>@socialM.site<br />
    }
```

The error I receive is "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement."  I have tried several variations and received several other errors.  Bottom line: how do I set the checked value in a dynamically-created list of checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor is very powerful in that it lets you mix code with html in an intuitive manner.  However, it mostly likes the code to be on one line and the html to be on a different line.  Here you might be trying to do too much on one line, so let's simplify that line.  What you really want is

```
<input type="checkbox" name="social" value="@socialM.ID" checked=@mycheckedvariable>@socialM.site<br />
```

Now let's figure out mycheckedvariable.  Find it in the loop, mostly as you have it

```
@foreach(var socialM in getSocMedia){
    string mycheckedvariable = "";
    foreach (var persmed in getPersMedia) {
       if (persmed.personID != null ) {
           mycheckedvariable = "checked";
           break;    // this exits the inner foreach loop
       }
    }
    <input type="checkbox" name="social" value="@socialM.ID" checked=@mycheckedvariable>@socialM.site<br />
}
```

Finally, mycheckedvariable is an awful name, pick something better.  And for my own code, i would probably use linq to determine if the checkbox should be set but that's beyond the scope of the answer.

Comment: This seems to be close. All boxes are checked, regardless of the values in the database. I tried tweaking the code, changing 'mycheckedvariable != null' to 'mycheckedvariable = null'. When I did that, I got this error: 'WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord' does not contain a definition for 'personID'. If it does not contain a definition, then I don't understand how it could have been evaluated to determine whether it is not null before I changed "!=" to "=".

Comment: Okay, dumb mistake. I forgot to use "==" instead of "=". However, all boxes are checked in either case, regardless of the data in the table. Not sure why.

Comment: Figured it out! All boxes were checked, regardless of the data in the database. When I checked the page source, the HTML for the checkboxes that should not be checked (but are checked) was:  <input type="checkbox" name="social" value="3" checked="">. I worked around this by replacing checked=@mycheckedvariable with checked="(@mycheckvariable.Length != 0)".

Comment: one bug in my code was that instead of checked=@mycheckedvariable, you could just put @mycheckvariable which will either have an empty string in it, or "checked", which would be a bit clearer.